# In intelliJ, is there a way to not have Optimize imports (Ctrl + Shift + O) break an import line into 2 because it exceeds the maximum line length?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have the IDE configured so that it breaks lines into 2 if the length exceeds 100. I don't wish this length limit to be respected for long imports, so I'd rather have this:

```
import com.x.y.LongFileName;
```

than this:

```
import com.x.y.
    LongFileName;
```

When I optimize imports to get rid of redundant imports, it splits the lines into 2. Is there a way to avoid this?